# Failed to load template in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside angulajs 1x app I have following structure

- app

  - common

    - js

      - directives

        notifications.js
      - templates

        notifications.html
  - security

notifications.js

```
(function(module) {    
    var notifications = function(notificating) {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            templateUrl: "templates/notifications.html",
// tried also   templateUrl: "../templates/notifications.html",
// tried also   templateUrl: "app/common/templates/notifications.html",
                link: function(scope) {
                // todo
            }
        };
    };    
    module.directive("notifications", notifications);
}(angular.module("common")));
```

inside firebug console I'm getting following error

> angular.js:9658 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///G:/My%20App/app/templates/notifications.html. Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.js:9658sendReq @ angular.js:9462serverRequest @
>   angular.js:9179processQueue @ angular.js:12914(anonymous function) @
>   angular.js:12930$eval @ angular.js:14123$digest @
>   angular.js:13939$apply @ angular.js:14227bootstrapApply @
>   angular.js:1487invoke @ angular.js:4152doBootstrap @
>   angular.js:1485bootstrap @ angular.js:1505angularInit @
>   angular.js:1399(anonymous function) @ angular.js:25579trigger @
>   angular.js:2742eventHandler @ angular.js:3013 angular.js:11358 Error:
>   [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: templates/templates.html
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$compile/tpload?p0=templates%2Ftemplates.html

Comment: You have to run this application in some server. Currently you are directly running accessing the file. You can take help of browser sync here.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory structure you have given is correct below should work.

```
templateUrl: "common/js/templates/notifications.html",
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start the path from the index.html.

So "common/js/templates/notifications.html" should work.